# The name 'MenuItem' is defined in the libraries cubit state and flutter_admin_scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[image]  hints--

[abstract class MenuItem with Diagnosticable, class MenuItem]
The name 'MenuItem' is defined in the libraries 'package:flutter/src/widgets/platform_menu_bar.dart' and 'package:flutter_admin_scaffold/src/menu_item.dart (via package:flutter_admin_scaffold/admin_scaffold.dart)'.
Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.dartambiguous_import
'MenuItem' isn't a function.
Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named 'MenuItem'.dartinvocation_of_non_function

### There are there package I used

1. cubit/cubit
2. cubit/states
3. flutter_admin_scaffold

> The error message: Problem is **AppLayout** Class and **MenuItem** (flutter_admin_scaffold)

*Please help me find out the problem and help me to slove the problem*

```
   import 'package:date_time_format/date_time_format.dart';
   import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'package:flutter_admin_scaffold/admin_scaffold.dart';
   import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
   import 'package:flutter_iconly/flutter_iconly.dart';
   import 'cubit/cubit.dart';
   import 'cubit/states.dart';
   
   class AppLayout extends StatelessWidget {
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return BlocConsumer<AppCubit, AppStates>(
         listener: (context, state) {},
         builder: (context, state) {
           var cubit = AppCubit.get(context);
           return AdminScaffold(
             backgroundColor: Colors.white,
             appBar: AppBar(
               title: const Text('Electronic App Admin',style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1),),
             ),
             sideBar: SideBar(
               items: const [
                 MenuItem(
                   title: 'Dashboard',
                   route: 'DashBoardScreen',
                   icon: Icons.dashboard,
                 ),
                 MenuItem(
                   title: 'Categories',
                   icon: IconlyLight.category,
                   children: [
                     MenuItem(
                       title: 'Category',
                       route: 'CategoryScreen',
                     ),
                     MenuItem(
                       title: 'Main Category',
                       route: 'MainCategoryScreen',
                     ),
                     MenuItem(
                       title: 'Sub Category',
                       route: 'SubCategoryScreen',
                     ),
                     MenuItem(
                       title: 'Vendor',
                       route: 'VendorScreen',
                       icon: Icons.group_add_outlined,
                     ),
                   ],
                 ),
               ],
               selectedRoute: 'AppLayout',
               onSelected: (item) {
                 AppCubit.get(context).screenSelector(item);
                 /*if (item.route != null) {
                   Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(item.route!);
                 }*/
               },
               header: Container(
                 height: 50,
                 width: double.infinity,
                 color: const Color(0xff444444),
                 child: const Center(
                   child: Text(
                     'Menu',
                     style: TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.white,
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
               footer: Container(
                 height: 50,
                 width: double.infinity,
                 color: const Color(0xff444444),
                 child:  Center(
                   child:  Text(
                     '${DateTimeFormat.format(DateTime.now(),format: AmericanDateFormats.dayOfWeek)}',
                     style: TextStyle(
                       color: Colors.white,
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
               ),
             ),
             body: SingleChildScrollView(
               child: AppCubit.get(context).selectorScreen,
             ),
           );
         },
       );
     }
   }
```

[image: Screenshot is here]

Answer (score 0):

The confliction is happening from `platform_menu_bar` and `flutter_admin_scaffold/src/menu_item`

You can import using `as` prefix

```dart
import 'package:flutter_admin_scaffold/admin_scaffold.dart' as adminScf;
```

To use its component, use `adminScf.`

```dart
adminScf.AdminMenuItem(
  title: 'Dashboard',
  route: 'DashBoardScreen',
  icon: Icons.dashboard,
),
```

`MenuItem` is an abstract class(on flutter source-code) and can't be use directly use inside`SideBar`'s `items`.

Try upgrading your packages and you can directly use `AdminMenuItem` from `flutter_admin_scaffold` without any prefix.

```dart
sideBar: SideBar(
    items: [
      AdminMenuItem(
        title: 'Dashboard',
        route: 'DashBoardScreen',
        icon: Icons.dashboard,
      ),
```

On this last snippet, I am using `flutter_admin_scaffold: ^1.1.1`

Tested widget

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_admin_scaffold/admin_scaffold.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: TestCW(),
  ));
}

class TestCW extends StatefulWidget {
  const TestCW({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<TestCW> createState() => _TestCWState();
}

class _TestCWState extends State<TestCW> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AdminScaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text(
          'Electronic App Admin',
          style: TextStyle(letterSpacing: 1),
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Text(""),
      ),
      sideBar: SideBar(
        items: [
          AdminMenuItem(
            title: 'Dashboard',
            route: 'DashBoardScreen',
            icon: Icons.dashboard,
          ),
          AdminMenuItem(
            title: 'Categories',
            children: [
              AdminMenuItem(
                title: 'Category',
                route: 'CategoryScreen',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
        selectedRoute: 'AppLayout',
        onSelected: (item) {},
        header: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: const Color(0xff444444),
          child: const Center(
            child: Text(
              'Menu',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        footer: Container(
          height: 50,
          width: double.infinity,
          color: const Color(0xff444444),
          child: Center(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Still same error, by the way thank you

Comment: You might replace with `AdminMenuItem` for this case, also try updgrading packages

Comment: I tried what are you say, but can't; still error. My humble request to you please write for me the full of code. and im also using it: flutter_admin_scaffold: ^1.1.1

Comment: you can run the *Tested widget*

Comment: [Drive project link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1REWkIGS6PApG620OVkDdtXrnR2s2HYEJ/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: try creating separate project and test the snippet

Comment: As Salaamu alaikum, of course way not. note: everything is ok when i add (cubit state) error show this time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246415/discussion-between-muhammad-arafat-and-yeasin-sheikh).